# Why is that although my pdf file is created, no information is passed to it and so I get an error while opening the file?

Tags: android, pdf

I am using itextpdf library to generate a PDF report within my android application. I have used this before in a previous app and it worked perfectly. The difference is, the previous app used one main activity with tabhosts. In the new app I am using viewpager in the main activity so I believe there will be a bit of a communication problem there passing information gotten from fragments to the main activity when the "save ticket" menu item is clicked in the main activity.

Below is the class to create the pdf file:

```
package com.application.sweetiean.stlservicing;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import com.application.sweetiean.stlmaintenance.Utility;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by sweetiean on 12/1/2015.
 */
public class Serv_CreatePDF {
public Serv_CreatePDF(){}

public Boolean writepdf(String sysaid) {
    try {
        String fpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + sysaid + ".pdf";
        File file = new File(fpath);
        // If file does not exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }



        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile()));

        Font font1 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16, Font.NORMAL);
        Font font2 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 20, Font.BOLDITALIC|Font.UNDERLINE);

        // step 3
        document.open();

        // step 4
        Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph("SERVICE REPORT", font2);
        paragraph1.setSpacingBefore(25);
        paragraph1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        paragraph1.setIndentationLeft(50);
        paragraph1.setIndentationRight(50);

        Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph(Utility.getTodaysDate(), font2);
        paragraph2.setSpacingAfter(25);
        //paragraph2.setSpacingBefore(25);
        paragraph2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        paragraph2.setIndentationLeft(50);
        paragraph2.setIndentationRight(50);

        Paragraph paragraph3 = new Paragraph("SERVICING", font2);
        paragraph1.setSpacingBefore(25);
        paragraph1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        paragraph1.setIndentationLeft(50);
        paragraph1.setIndentationRight(50);

        Paragraph paragraph4 = new Paragraph("REPLACEMENT", font2);
        paragraph1.setSpacingBefore(25);
        paragraph1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        paragraph1.setIndentationLeft(50);
        paragraph1.setIndentationRight(50);

        document.add(paragraph1);
        document.add(paragraph2);
        document.add(new Paragraph("Sysaid ID: " + Serv_BaseDataFragment.sysaid.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Task Type: " + Serv_BaseDataFragment.taskSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Customer: " + Serv_BaseDataFragment.customer.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Site ID: " + Serv_BaseDataFragment.siteId.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Address: " + Serv_BaseDataFragment.address.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Region: " + Serv_BaseDataFragment.regionSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Location Coordinates: " + Serv_BaseDataFragment.locationCoordinates.getText().toString(), font1));

        document.add(new Paragraph(" "));
        document.add(paragraph3);

        document.add(new Paragraph("DVR Firmware Update: " + ((ServicingFragment.dvrFirmware.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Firmware Version: " + ServicingFragment.firmwareVersion.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Workstation: " + ((ServicingFragment.workstation.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Test Computer Performance: " + ((ServicingFragment.testCP.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Clean Computer: " + ((ServicingFragment.cleanPC.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Serial Number: " + ServicingFragment.workstationSerial.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Remarks: " + ServicingFragment.remarks.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("DVR: " + ((ServicingFragment.dvr.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Serial Number: " + ServicingFragment.dvrSerial.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Service and Clean Cameras: " + ((ServicingFragment.cleanCam.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Check UPS Backup Status: " + ((ServicingFragment.checkUPS.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("UPS: " + ServicingFragment.UPSSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Serial Number: " + ServicingFragment.UPSSerial.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Status: " + ServicingFragment.statusSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), font1));

        document.add(new Paragraph(" "));
        document.add(paragraph4);

        document.add(new Paragraph("UPS: " + ((ReplacementFragment.UPS.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("UPS Type: " + ReplacementFragment.UPSSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Serial Number: " + ReplacementFragment.UPSSerial.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Workstation: " + ((ReplacementFragment.workstation.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Serial Number: " + ReplacementFragment.workstationSerial.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hard Disk Drive: " + ((ReplacementFragment.hdd.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("500GB: " + ((ReplacementFragment._500GB.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("1TB: " + ((ReplacementFragment._1TB.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("2TB: " + ((ReplacementFragment._2TB.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Serial Number: " + ReplacementFragment.hddSerial.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("DVR: " + ((ReplacementFragment.dvr.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("DVR Type: " + ReplacementFragment.dvrType.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Serial Number: " + ReplacementFragment.dvrSerial.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Cameras: " + ((ReplacementFragment.cameras.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Fix Box: " + ((ReplacementFragment.fixBox.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Quantity: " + ReplacementFragment.fixBoxQty.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Serial Number: " + ReplacementFragment.fixBoxSerial.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Dome IR: " + ((ReplacementFragment.domeIR.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Quantity: " + ReplacementFragment.domeOty.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Serial Number: " + ReplacementFragment.domeSerial.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Bullet IR: " + ((ReplacementFragment.bulletIR.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Quantity: " + ReplacementFragment.bulletQty.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Serial Number: " + ReplacementFragment.bulletSerial.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Housing: " + ((ReplacementFragment.housing.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Quantity: " + ReplacementFragment.housingQty.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Serial Number: " + ReplacementFragment.housingSerial.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Power Supply: " + ((ReplacementFragment.powerSupply.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("12V DC Power Supply: " + ((ReplacementFragment._12vPwrSupply.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("12V DC Power Box: " + ((ReplacementFragment._12vPwrBox.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Monitor: " + ((ReplacementFragment.monitor.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Serial Number: " + ReplacementFragment.monitorSerial.getText().toString(), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Other Issues: " + ((ReplacementFragment.otherIssues.isChecked()) ? "Checked" : "Not Checked"), font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Issues: " + ReplacementFragment.issues.getText().toString(), font1));

        document.add(new Paragraph(" "));
        document.add(new Paragraph("STL Rep Name: " + Serv_BaseDataFragment.stl_rep_name, font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("STL Rep Position: " + Serv_BaseDataFragment.stl_rep_post, font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("STL Rep Signature: ", font1));
        String stl_filePathSign = STLSignatureActivity.tempDir +
                Serv_BaseDataFragment.stl_rep_sign;
        Image stl_imgSign = Image.getInstance(stl_filePathSign);
        stl_imgSign.scaleToFit(150, 150);
        document.add(stl_imgSign);

        document.add(new Paragraph(" "));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Client Rep Name: " + Serv_BaseDataFragment.client_rep_name, font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Client Rep Position: " + Serv_BaseDataFragment.client_rep_post, font1));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Client Rep Signature: ", font1));
        String client_filePathSign = STLSignatureActivity.tempDir +
                Serv_BaseDataFragment.client_rep_sign;
        Image client_imgSign = Image.getInstance(client_filePathSign);
        client_imgSign.scaleToFit(150, 150);
        document.add(client_imgSign);

        // step 5
        document.close();

        Log.d("Success", "Success");
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}


}
```

Below is the Activity in which I try to call the pdf class:

```
public class ServicingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String url;
SharedPreferences settings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_servicing);

    init();

}

public void init(){

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Serv_OverviewFragment(), "Overview");
    adapter.addFragment(new Serv_BaseDataFragment(), "Base Data");
    adapter.addFragment(new ServicingFragment(), "Servicing");
    adapter.addFragment(new ReplacementFragment(), "Replacement");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}




/*public void save_final(){

    Serv_BaseDataFragment baseFragment = (Serv_BaseDataFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.baseDataTab);
    baseFragment.serv_insertToBaseData_db();

    ServicingFragment serviceFragment = (ServicingFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.servicingTab);
    serviceFragment.insertToServicing_db();

    ReplacementFragment replaceFragment = (ReplacementFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.baseDataTab);
    replaceFragment.insertToReplacement_db();

    Toast.makeText(this, "ALL DATA STORED SUCCESSFULLY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);


}*/

public void writePdf(){
    String filename = Serv_BaseDataFragment.sysaid.getText().toString();

    Serv_CreatePDF fop = new Serv_CreatePDF();

    if (fop.writepdf(filename)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filename +  ".pdf created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I/O error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_maintenance, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Serv_SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.save_tickets) {
        //save_final();
        writePdf();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

The toast keeps giving me an I/O Error. When I debug, the file is created but no data is written to it. And I can confirm the file creates when i check from the file manager on my device.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: which itext version do you use?

Comment: @mkl the version is 5.5.3

Comment: And just to make sure... you use the itextg library variant for GAE and Android, don't you?

Comment: @mkl to be honest I don't know what that is.

Comment: There is a special edition of iText for Google App Engine and Android called [itextg](http://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android). This edition is stripped of references to Java classes and packages not available in those environments; e.g. the java.awt packages. Standard iText does reference java.awt and, therefore, might cause trouble when used on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was facing was as a result of a signature image I was trying to add to the document. `String client_filePathSign = STLSignatureActivity.tempDir +
                Serv_BaseDataFragment.client_rep_sign;` I was repeating the same activity as the initial signature image. `STLSignatureActivity` should have been `ClientSignatureActivity`. It was a copy and paste gone wrong.